# c++ how to make constructor for typedef type

Tags: c++, typedef

In my c++ project I have a type called Expression

```cpp
typedef std::function<uint64_t(uint64_t)> Expression;
```

I also have a function which acts like a constructor

```cpp
Expression ExpressionConstructor(std::string Expr, MicroCodeDescriptor* descriptor) {
//implementation doesn't matter in this case
}
```

This code works, I can use the Expression type like this:

```cpp
Expression expr= ExpressionConstructor(code, descriptor);
```

But is there any way to declare a constructor for Expression that syntactically works like a constructor instead of like a separate function, I don't see any reason why this is fundamentally impossible as constructors are just functions with the return type of the class they construct.

Comment: `ExpressionConstructor` looks like a factory function, except that it has an odd name. What is the reason why you don't want to use a factory function and need something that behaves like a constructor?.

Comment: Constructors don't have *any* return type. Constructors and destructors are "special" functions that don't have names, don't return anything, and can't be called.

Comment: @GideonMax The standard (see the `[special]` section.) is very clear on this: "Constructors do not have names." (thus, you can't refer to it for calls or anything else) and "A constructor is used to initialize objects of its class type." (Thus, it does not create an object, much less return one.)  The compiler can of course refer to the constructor and call it, but you can't, and what name the compiler uses and how it's called are completely irrelevant implementation details.

Comment: @molbdnilo 
1. the constructor receives the address that will be used for the object AND returns it, the disassembly doesn't lie.

2. 
```

 CodeTreePart part(str);

 CodeTreePart part=CodeTreePart::CodeTreePart(str);

```
these two lines of code are (almost) equivalent and are both valid and work (I tested this)
not sure what you are referring to but the real world disagrees, are you sure you aren't reading an old c++ standard?
p.s. the difference between the lines is that the second initializes and then assignes, the first just initializes

Comment: @GideonMax  As any non-beginner knows, `CodeTreePart part=CodeTreePart::CodeTreePart(str);` is not an assignment (and I have no idea what point you're trying to make with that example). And you can't determine language semantics by studying generated code.

Comment: @molbdnilo the line shows that you can call a constructor and if you took a minute and looked at the disassembly, this line first constructs a new object and then "moves" it into the variable part, clearly there is assignment here.
the given line is equivalent to part.operator=(CodeTreePart::CodeTreePart(str));

Comment: @GideonMax It's a copy-initialization, not an assignment. People usually notice the difference when they write their first overload of the assignment operator. Also, `CodeTreePart::CodeTreePart(str)` is equivalent to `CodeTreePart(str)`. And again, the disassembly is an implementation detail, but what you're seeing is the compiler invoking the constructor behind the scene as part of the process of creating an object.

Comment: @molbdnilo so what you're saying is, by typing CodeTreePart(str), I'm not calling the constructor, I'm telling the compiler to call the constructor. well, of course, when I type x++ I'm not incrementing x I'm telling the compiler to increment x, I don't get why you think you can't call constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `typedef` your Expression could be a class derived from `std::function<uint64_t(uint64_t)>`. Then you can define its *constructor(s)*, *destructor* and call it as a `std::function`:

```
struct Expression : public std::function<uint64_t(uint64_t)>
{
    Expression(std::string Expr, MicroCodeDescriptor* descriptor)
    {

    }
};

Expression e = Expression("", nullptr);
uint64_t res = e(123);
```

Or even better make it template:

```
template<typename R = uint64_t, typename T = uint64_t>
struct Expression : public std::function<R(T)>
...
```

Comment: yeah, I have decided to opt for that option, though I have absolutely no reason to use templates here

Answer (score 4):

A `typedef` is not a new type, it just creates an alias, your `Expression` is still the type `std::function<uint64_t(uint64_t)>`.

> I don't see any reason why this is fundamentally impossible as constructors are just functions with the return type of the class they construct.

It isn't fundamentally impossible (in the sense that the specification could not allow such a thing), but there is no such functionality given in the specification so you can't do it. Just as it is not possible to add a new member function to an existing type.